TypeOrm : issue with the returning clause in createQueryBuilder
i'm using postgresql as DB and i need to create an service where i insert data in multiple tables from the inserted data in the first table,
so here you are the context :
i need to insert data in table A and from the table A i need to return id, startHour and endHour column and then i need to calculate the difference between the two times and then i need to calculate the hourlyRate, the hourlyRate is a column of the second table (table C) so what i thought about is to create the query to insert data and then return the needed column and then create the other query, this is the code :
.returning(['id','startHour','endHour','EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM(endHour - startHour) / 3600) as duration'])
console.log('sessionInsertResult', sessionInsertResult)
const session = sessionInsertResult.generatedMaps[0] as Session
console.log('session', session)

the issue here is the duration didn't returned by the way i have tried to run the query :
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ("endHour" - "startHour")/ 3600) AS duration
FROM 
    public.session
WHERE 
    id = 'e4a1dc74-be6f-4cba-97b7-303e5d69b3b4';

and it gives the required column with the correct value.
so my idea was to separate the queries :
so my idea was to separate the queries like this :
const session = this.sessionRepository.create({
            date: payload.date,
            startHour: payload.startHour,
            endHour: payload.endHour,
            gymId: coach.gymId,
            coachId: coach.id,
            disciplineId: payload.disciplineId,
        })

        const savedSession = await this.sessionRepository.save(session)

        const sessionId = savedSession.id

        const sessionDuration = await this.sessionRepository.query(
            `
                    SELECT 
                        id, 
                        "startHour", 
                        "endHour", 
                        EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ("endHour" - "startHour") / 3600) AS duration
                    FROM 
                        public.session
                    WHERE 
                        id = $1
                    `,
            [sessionId]
        )

thank you for your help, it will be grate if you look with me for a solution .
Note: i have made some research an i have found that typeOrm have some limitation and can't handle the calculation and return it as new column ...
